# Wrong count for nested facets

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm building search for products and variants. One product can have many nested variants. Example: 1 T-shirt can be in 2 variants, white for 50 euros and green for 60 euros. It's still the same product and should be displayed once on the results page.

This is my mapping:

```
{"product" => { "properties" => {"vendor_variants" => {"type" => "nested"}}}}
```

And this is the query that I'm doing:

```
"query" => {
    "filtered" => {
      "query" => {
        "match_all" => {}
      },
      "filter" => {
        "bool" => {
          "must" => [
            {
              "terms" => {
                "categories" => [122]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "facets" => {
    "brand" => { "terms" => {"field" => "filter_brand"} },
    "price_range" => {
      "nested" => "vendor_variants",
      "range" => { "field" => "price", "ranges" => [ {"to" => 2000}, {"from" => 2000, "to" => 5000} ]
      }
    }
  }
```

This query produces 172 results. But the facets for price ranges are completely wrong. For example it returns that for 20-50 euro range there are 422 results. I believe it's because it counts every single nested vendor_variants document. But it's not what I need, I need it to count only the main product documents.

What is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. In mapping for the nested document, I had to add `"include_in_parent" => true`